# checking in List<SelectItem> contain this part of string or not in java

Tags: java, list, object, contains

I have an arrayList with

```
List<SelectItem> list= new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

list.add(new SelectItem("abcdefg");
```

I need to check whther string `"abc"` contains or part of the selectItem object.

Whats the best way to achieve that.Please suggest.

Comment: Can you share `SelectItem`  class code?

Comment: What is the use-case? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

this assumes that SelectItem is similar to the JSF SelectItem, and that getValue() returns a String. It can also be applied to getLabel() (same JSF SelectItem assumption).

```
for(SelectItem item : list) {
    if(item.getValue().indexOf("abc") != -1) {
        // you have it
    } else {
        // you don't
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way under Java 8:

```
if(list.stream().filter(x -> ( (x.getValue()==null)?false:x.getValue().toString().contains("abc") ) )
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent()) {
    // action when found 
} 
else {   
    // action when not found 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming SelectItem has a getValue() method:

```
List<SelectItem> list= new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
list.add(new SelectItem("abcdefg");

booleand found = false;

for(SelectItem item:list){
  if(item.getValue().contains("abc")){
    found = true;
    // action when found

    // if you only need the first hit use "break;"
  }
}
if(!found){
  System.out.println("'abc'is not found in the selectitems. ");
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to loop over the list. Is their more elegant way of doing that

Comment: what is the problem with looping? how else do you think you can go search throu a set of items? You cant know what item is the 'right' one without looking in the items.. hence u need to loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a partial string, you will need to iterate over the elements to check if one of them has the partial string in them.

Comment: cant we do by overriding equal method.What people say I have to iterate the whole list.I dont want that